# c - segfault in gdk function if assigning value to (subsequent) struct variables

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk, gdk

## Description

I'm having trouble tracking down the cause of a segfault (no core dump).
When assigning a values (from another variable) to `*trans_theta`, `*trans_x`, or `*trans_y`, **my program gives a segfault when I close the GUI window**. Backtrace gives a series of `g_xxx`, `gdk_xxx`, and `gtk_xxx` functions. Simply getting rid of these lines eliminates the fault.

Program exits normally if I only close the GUI window (no click data).

I've used this same method in multiple functions with struct members under the same or similar umbrella - this makes me think I've got some fundamental misunderstanding of GTK or memory.

**Here's the header file:**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#ifndef _ROVER_GUI
#define _ROVER_GUI

#define WINDOW_CTR_X 220
#define WINDOW_CTR_Y 220
#define MIN_RADIUS 20
#define PI 3.1415926535897932382646
#define WHEEL_ANGLE 0.7853981633974483096156 // PI/4

typedef struct gui_obj{
    GtkBuilder * builder;
    GtkWidget * window;
    GtkWidget * img;
    GdkPixbuf * icon;
    GError * error;
} s_gui;

typedef struct point_obj{
    int x;  // x-coordinate of point
    int y;  // y-coordinate of point
    double theta; // Angle of (x,y), +/- pi (+/- 180 degrees)
    double mag;   // Magnitude (hypotenuse) of (x,y)
} s_point;

typedef struct data_obj{
    // GUI INPUTS
    // **********
    // Coordinates of mouse pointer on click (relative to window origin)
    // and coordinates of window center (relative to window origin)
    s_point ptr_loc;
    s_point ctr_loc;

    s_point delta;  // Vector from window center to pointer
    s_point trans;  // s_delta translated to wheel coordinates
} s_data;

#endif
```

**And here's the program file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "rover_gui.h"


// Function to calculate vector 
int calcVector( int * x1, int * y1, int * x2, int * y2, int * dx, int * dy )
{
    // Calculate vector from point 1 to point 2
    *dx = *x2 - *x1;
    *dy = *y2 - *y1;
    
    return 0;
}


// Function to correct y-dir portion of vector (screen coords to cartesian)
int correctVector( int * dx, int * dy, double * angle, double * magnitude )
{
    // Invert dy coordinate
    *dy = -(*dy);

    
    // Calculate magnitude and assign value
    double mag = pow( (*dx)*(*dx) + (*dy)*(*dy), 0.5 );
    
    
    // Calculate angle and assign value
    double theta;
    if( mag == 0.0 ){
        theta = 0.0;
    }
    else{
        theta = acos( (*dx) / pow( (*dx)*(*dx) + (*dy)*(*dy), 0.5 ) ); // Calculate angle
    }

    *magnitude = mag; // Set input point value
    *angle = theta;
    
    
    
    return 0;
}


// Calculate motor outputs
int calcVectorInWheelSystem( double * mag, double * theta,
                             int * trans_x, int * trans_y,
                             double * trans_mag, double * trans_theta )
{
    // Transform input vector to wheel coordinate system
    double new_mag = *mag;
    double new_theta;
    if( ((*theta) < -.75*PI) && ((*theta) > -PI) ){ // From -135 to -180 deg
        new_theta = (PI + *theta) + PI - WHEEL_ANGLE; // in radians
    }
    else{
        new_theta = *theta - WHEEL_ANGLE; // in radians
    }

    int new_x;
    int new_y;
    new_x = (int)(new_mag * cos( new_theta ));
    new_y = (int)(new_mag * sin( new_theta ));

    *trans_mag = new_mag;
    *trans_theta = new_theta;
    *trans_x = new_x;
    *trans_y = new_y;
    
    
    return 0;
}


// Function to print out coordinates received from gtk_main() events
void takeItAway( s_data * sp_data )
{
    // USE input coordinates to calculate directional vector
    int ret = 0;
    ret = calcVector(&(sp_data->ctr_loc.x), &(sp_data->ctr_loc.y),
                     &(sp_data->ptr_loc.x), &(sp_data->ptr_loc.y),
                     &(sp_data->delta.x), &(sp_data->delta.y) );
    if( ret != 0 ){
        printf( "Failed in calcVector.\n" );
    }
    
    
    // CORRECT y-coordinate (invert)
    ret = correctVector( &(sp_data->delta.x), &(sp_data->delta.y),
                         &(sp_data->delta.theta), &(sp_data->delta.mag) );
    if( ret != 0 ){
        printf( "Failed in correctVector.\n" );
    }
            
    
    // CONVERT input vector to Wheel System coordinates
    ret = calcVectorInWheelSystem(  &(sp_data->delta.mag), &(sp_data->delta.theta),
                                    &(sp_data->trans.x), &(sp_data->trans.y),
                                    &(sp_data->trans.mag), &(sp_data->trans.theta) );
    if( ret != 0 ){
        printf( "Failed in calcVectorInWheelSystem.\n" );
    }
    
}



// Function to initialize GUI
int initGUI( s_gui * p_gui, int * arg_num, char ** arg_vec[] )
{
    // Initialize error to NULL, initialize GTK
    p_gui->error = NULL;
    gtk_init( arg_num, arg_vec );
    
    
    // Initialize Builder object and use it to create the gui from the glade file
    p_gui->builder = gtk_builder_new( );
    if( !gtk_builder_add_from_file( p_gui->builder, "rover_gui.glade", &p_gui->error ) ){
        g_warning( "%s", p_gui->error->message );
        g_free( p_gui->error );
        return 1;
    }

    
    // Use Builder to connect gui objects to pointers and signals, then unreference
    p_gui->window = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( p_gui->builder, "window0" ) );
    p_gui->img = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( p_gui->builder, "img0" ) );
    gtk_builder_connect_signals( p_gui->builder, p_gui );
    g_object_unref( p_gui->builder );
    
    
    //Show window
    gtk_widget_show( p_gui->window );

    
    return 0;
}


// Signal handler for Event Box button press event
void on_ebox0_button_press_event( GtkWidget * widget, GdkEvent * event, gpointer user_data )
{
    s_data * sp_data = user_data;
    // Assign event data (pointer coordinates on click) to data struct
    sp_data->ptr_loc.x = event->button.x;
    sp_data->ptr_loc.y = event->button.y;
    sp_data->ctr_loc.x = WINDOW_CTR_X;
    sp_data->ctr_loc.y = WINDOW_CTR_Y;

    
    // Take it away, Ern!
    takeItAway( sp_data );
}


// Signal handler for Event Box button release event
void on_ebox0_button_release_event( GtkWidget * widget, GdkEvent * event, s_data * sp_data )
{
    // Possible future implementation
}


// Called when window is closed
void on_window0_destroy( )
{
    gtk_main_quit( );
}


// Main
int main( int arg_num, char * arg_vec[] )
{   
    // Initialize GUI
    s_gui * p_gui = g_slice_new( s_gui );
    int pass = initGUI( p_gui, &arg_num, &arg_vec );
    if( pass != 0 ){
        printf( "Failed in initGui.\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    // Begin GUI main
    gtk_main( );

    
    // Free GUI memory
    g_slice_free( s_gui, p_gui );
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

*EDIT* I forgot to include the glade file! (Thanks John):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window0">
    <property name="name">window0</property>
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can-focus">True</property>
    <property name="has-focus">True</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">440</property>
    <property name="default-height">440</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window0_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkEventBox" id="ebox0">
        <property name="name">ebox0</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <signal name="button-press-event" handler="on_ebox0_button_press_event" swapped="no"/>
        <signal name="button-release-event" handler="on_ebox0_button_release_event" swapped="no"/>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkImage" id="img0">
            <property name="name">img0</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="sensitive">False</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="pixbuf">gui_background.png</property>
            <property name="icon_size">6</property>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**And here is the backtrace:**

```
#0  0x00007ffff7289c11 in gdk_screen_get_default () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7a4f5b3 in gtk_widget_get_display () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7a0b0fe in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7a49ca9 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7a4c17c in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff7a4f3e4 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff7a5d226 in gtk_widget_unparent () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff77d7508 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff76703ad in g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__OBJECTv ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff766d2ee in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff7685a48 in g_signal_emit_valist () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff7685c3f in g_signal_emit () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff78277a5 in gtk_container_remove () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff7a540d4 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff7673439 in g_object_run_dispose () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff7a60829 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff7829486 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff766d0a2 in g_closure_invoke () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff767f3ad in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff76856cf in g_signal_emit_valist () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff7685c3f in g_signal_emit () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff7a541b0 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff7a67a78 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#23 0x00007ffff7673439 in g_object_run_dispose () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007ffff78ffa3d in gtk_main_do_event () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff7a61737 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#26 0x00007ffff727fdd9 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff757bd6f in g_main_context_dispatch () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff757c118 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff757c40b in g_main_loop_run () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff78fea65 in gtk_main () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#31 0x0000555555555912 in main (arg_num=1, arg_vec=0x7fffffffe098) at smallest_example.c:217
```

## Attempts

By commenting things out, I've found that in `calcVectorInWheelSystem`, `*trans_theta`, `*trans_x`, and `*trans_y` all cause a segfault, but I have the sneaking suspicion I've messed up something somewhere else.
Setting these to constants causes a series of GTK/GDK critical errors.
Setting these to the values of input variables (e.g., `*theta`) causes a segfault in a different `g_xxx` function.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is probably related to how you wire up your widgets, and especially the event-handler function `on_ebox0_button_press_event()`.  Almost certainly, that function is being called with a third argument (the user data pointer) that is null or invalid.  That gets passed to `takeItAway()`, and the pointers ultimately passed to `calcVectorInWheelSystem()` are derived from it.  It appears that the details of how it is wired up are in your Glade file, which you have not presented, but that's probably just as well because wading through that would be painful.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for taking a look at it. I checked the user_data pointer; it's not null, tho I'm not sure how to tell if it's invalid. Also I should mention the segfault happens when trying to close the window, not while I'm clicking around in the GUI.

Comment: I don't know much about GTK, but is calling `g_object_unref( p_gui->builder );` in `initGUI()` the correct thing to do?

Comment: You have associated the failure behavior with the user_data pointer by observing that the failures are strongly correlated with the presence of assignments through pointers derived from that pointer.  That the errors are raised when you close the application window instead of when you actually perform assignments through those derived pointers in no way conflicts with the conclusion that the pointer's value is inappropriate for its use.  That it's not null is unsurprising under the circumstances.  Most likely it is a dangling pointer, a wild pointer, or a pointer to the wrong kind of object.

Comment: So start by figuring out where that value is coming from.

Comment: ... which may be nowhere, or some default.  Because I don't see anything in the Glade file that would configure it.

Comment: Documentation about how to choose the `user_data` via the Glade GUI seems hard to come by, but there are some indications that the only values you can configure there are GUI components (by name).  That would be a limitation of Glade, not of GTK.  If you're committed to Glade, then you might be best off choosing using a different mechanism than the `user_data` to convey the object to operate upon to your callback.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Adding the data-struct to the GUI-struct (which I had done in previous projects, but not _this_ one!) gets rid of the segfault. Should I interpret this as my data-struct had a rando-pointer and ended up overlapping with other memory? Like you said, the problem was related to how I wire up widgets. Clearly I need to do some more GTK-fundamentals studying; I had just been copying and modifying from my previous working projects =O . Thanks again for your insights.